# Using Stone–Weierstrass theorem for completely regular space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be completely regular. If $K$ is a compact subset of $X$, define $$p_K(f)=\sup\{|f(x)|;x\in X\}$$ 
then $\{p_k; \text{K is a compact }\}$ is a family of seminorms that makes $C(X)$ into a Locally convex space .    If $\cal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(X)$ that separates the points of $X$ and $1\in {\cal A}$ and $\bar{f} \in {\cal A}  $  whenever $f \in  {\cal A}$,  then $ {\cal A}=C(X).$

I want to use this theorem for proving:

Theorem: Let $X$ be completely regular and let $M$ be a linear manifold in $C(X)$. if for every compact subset $K$ of $X$, $M_{|K}=\{f_{|K}; f\in M\}$ is dense in $C(K)$, then $M$ is dense in $C(X)$.

I think  I should  show every ${\cal A}_{|K}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(K)$. But I can not show that  ${\cal A}_{|K}$ is closed.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The theorem in the first paragraph isn't true as stated. Did you leave out the word "closed"?

Comment: I understood the answer several days ago. It's not necessary to show ${\cal A}_{|K}$ is closed, just show that it's dense in $C(K)$ is sufficient.